# GPUs for motion graphics

Tags: hardware

What are a few common GPUs that offer the best hardware acceleration for motion graphics and compositing? (i.e. After Effects, Motion, Combustion, etc)

Comment: Probably some good shopping criteria here: http://blogs.adobe.com/aftereffects/2012/05/gpu-cuda-opengl-features-in-after-effects-cs6.html

Answer (score 1):

Currently Adobe products only support hardware with CUDA support.  While there is a specific list on Adobe's website of officially supported hardware, most cards with CUDA support will work with a little bit of tweaking.  The best bet is probably to Google for the particular card you are interested in and the package you want to use as the exact support and capabilities of each card/software combination will vary.